# Efficient ways to filter unwanted data from a buffer in c++

Tags: c++, string, parsing

Lets assume, data is stored in a character buffer in below format

```
===========================================================================
|length| message1| length| message2| length| message3|...|length |messagen|
===========================================================================
```

Length - indicates size of following message

From this character buffer, suppose only message2 is unwanted and rest all are relevant,
How efficiently, message2 can be removed so that rest all data in buffer can be used happily?

I have come accross, in-place algorithm, where we can shift the messages in the buffer itself without any additional copy

But with this also, there is an overhead of shifting (n-2) messages because message2 is irrelevant

Is there any better approach/ solution to it to do in c++?

Let me add more details- 
Requirement here is need to remove/filter irrelevant data from the buffer and then pass it as input to another function for further processing

irrelevant data can come at any position in the character buffer. Just for example, referred as message 2

Comment: You could leave the string alone entirely and represent the filtered view as `std::vector<std::string_view>`. or `std::array<std::string_view, 2>`.

Comment: I would use `memmove`

Comment: Does it matter? Can you not just ignore it or are you prefiltering for a future consumer?

Comment: filter view of your character buffer (but you filter would be called each time :/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to actually remove this from the buffer? Then the most efficient way to move it is to just shift everything after it over it with a single move (not n-2). If the message isn't using a lot of memory you can probably just skip over it for most applications though.

Comment: Do the remaining messages need to be contiguous?

Comment: What do you want to do with the buffer after you remove the unused data?

Comment: According to the laws of physics of our shared universe, if `#N` bytes need to be shifted in memory, to replace the gap caused by removed data, then the only way to do this is to copy `#N` bytes. Unfortunately, there is no convenient wormhole that can be employed to make all these bytes move all by themselves, in less time than it takes to copy `#N` bytes in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how many bits are in your length field, but assuming you can spare an extra bit to make the length-values signed rather than unsigned, I'd be tempted to adopt a convention that says "if a length-header has a negative value, that indicates that the its message-body is invalid and should be ignored".

Once you've adopted that convention, then flagging message 2 as invalid is just a matter of overwriting its length-header with the negation of its current value.

Of course, the code that is reading the buffer later on has to also follow the convention, so if e.g. if it sees a length-header with value of -57 then it should just skip ahead by 57 bytes without processing them.

Comment: You don't have to make the `length` field be a signed type for this to work. As long as you can preserve the high bit, an unsigned field will also work fine. Simply set/test the high bit when needed, and mask off that bit when reading the value of the length. No negation needed, that is just wasted cycles

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was any measurable efficiency-difference between (negating an integer) and (performing bit-mask operations on an integer).  Therefore either way will work fine; it's mostly a matter of coding-style preference.